# Conversion from SharePoint services 2.0 to SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We need to migrate from Sharepoint Services 2.0 to Sharepoint Foundation 2010.
We have about 100 customer sites and 20 document libraries that we would like to bring over.

How much time should it take if we were to get a seasoned consultant for this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two weeks max if you know what your doing!

how do i know? im doing it atm!

It involves moving the content DB, this is what i have drawn out:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee947141(v=office.14).aspx

1)  Run prescan.exe 2003, check there are no errors before proceeding

2)  Go to SharePoint 2003 SQL database, backup content DB

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299(v=office.12).aspx

3)  Go to SharePoint 2007 and create a new Web application

4)  Detach the SharePoint 2007 web application from the new content DB

5)  Restore from the backup (2003) to the 2007 DB

6)  Go to central admin and attach 2003 content DB to the SharePoint 2007 web application.

7)  Upgrade

8)  Make sure all is running correctly on the farm

9)  Review upgrade log file

10) Run prescan.exe 2007, make sure there are no errors

11) Do same again for 2010 following the same steps above

12) Run prescan.exe 2010

13) Review the report generated by the custom utility

14) Configure access security

15) Rebuild search index

its a complex issue and will give you a headake! im presuming that you will do a dummy run first ;), you need to also make the layout in SQL and sharepoint 2010.

the content DB is called a complex double database upgrade approach :) , but if its a contractor I would have it at 2 weeks!! 3 to be on the safe side!

Also bare in mind that it will double your SQL database due to the fact that 2003 - 2010 DB is vastly different and in any upgrade the DB would need other tables procedures ect to make the link, compared to a fresh install of 2010 and a new DB! As you can see im upgrading with an intermediat (wss 3.0 sharepoint 2007) as there is no direct upgrade and server 2003 needs wss 2.0 on sharepoint 2003!

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to provide a number for this as there are too many variables involved that can double or even quintuple (or more!) an estimate.  Everything from how prepared the organization is for the transition to how the current site is being used to how the current site is maintained can affect it.  Also keep in mind that there is no direct upgrade path from SP2003 so SP2010 and you will either have to upgrade your content through an SP2007 farm or purchase a third party utility (i.e. DocAve or Quest) that will leapfrog into 2010.  There is also a culture shock and training that will need to be done for the organization as SP2010 is considerably different that SP2003.

However, a one to three day discovery period should be able to narrow down the amount of time it would take to a solid estimate as they will be able to identify and isolate many of the larger variables.

In the absolute best-case textbook upgrade possible, It shouldn't take more than a few days.  However, I have yet to actually see one of those in the real world...

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on following factors,

- Complexity of your current System as if how deep it has been customized.
- Size of content residing in your system.
- Abilities of Consultant.

I am afraid if anyone here will be able to provide close enough time scale to you, but I would say it will be in months.

Since you are migrating I am pretty sure you would like to use new features of newer version hence that will take extra time too.